# Can I do this without reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, mvvm, expression-trees

For a presentation involving six components of a Person object's PersonName, I added an extension and a 'mini view model' (PersonNamePropertyTextBox) to cut down on duplicated code and facilitate data binding.

So in the constructor of the parent view model, I create these mini view models like:

```
   public PimDetailVm(Person person, ..) 
    {
        LastName = new PersonNamePropertyTextBox(
            () => Model.GetPersonName().LastName, v => this.UpdatePersonNameProperty(pn => pn.LastName, v))
        {
            Label = PeopleResources.LastName_Label
        };

        FirstName = new PersonNamePropertyTextBox(
            () => Model.GetPersonName().FirstName, v => this.UpdatePersonNameProperty(pn => pn.FirstName, v))
        {
            Label = PeopleResources.FirstName_Label
        };

        ... etc.
    }

    public PersonNamePropertyTextBox LastName { get; private set; }
    public PersonNamePropertyTextBox FirstName { get; private set; }
```

What I would *really* like now is to be able to do is just pass in the current property, ie "LastName" and the label value, and let the mini view model set the appropriate Getter/Setter delegates, something like:

```
LastName = new PersonNamePropertyTextBox(vm=>LastName, PeopleResources.LastName_Label);
```

I am struggling as to how to do this though. Any ideas?

## Extension (handle updating the PersonName in the Model)

```
    public static void UpdatePersonNameProperty(this PimDetailVm vm, Expression<Func<PersonName, object>> propertyExpression, string value)
    {
        var pn = vm.Model.GetPersonName();
        var pnProps = pn.GetType().GetProperties();

        var subj = ExprHelper.GetPropertyName(propertyExpression);
        var subjProp = pnProps.Single(pi => pi.Name.Equals(subj));

        var currentVal = subjProp.GetValue(pn, null);

        // split if there is nothing to update
        if(currentVal==null && value==null) return;
        if (currentVal != null && currentVal.Equals(value)) return;

        // update the property
        var capitalized = value == null ? null : value.Capitalize();
        subjProp.SetValue(pn, capitalized, null);

        // update the model
        vm.Model.SetName(pn);

        // broadcast the update
        vm.NotifyOfPropertyChange(subj, value);
    }
```

## Mini View Model for some property of a PersonName

```
public class PersonNamePropertyTextBox : TextBoxActionData
{
    public PersonNamePropertyTextBox(Func<string> getterFunc, Action<string> setterAction) {
        if (getterFunc == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("getterFunc");
        if (setterAction == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("setterAction");

        GetterFunc = getterFunc;
        SetterAction = setterAction;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid reflection?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Interesting question, I try and avoid reflection roughly like traffic jams. I don't like to drive in busy traffic but sometimes you just have to...

Comment: @CodeInChaos, all things being equal -- i.e. if you can solve a problem equally well with and without reflection -- the solution that does not use reflection is better because it is more type-safe.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this without reflection, but there is a way to make reflection MUCH faster using delegates. Check out this link, http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx

Comment: static reflection is already pretty type safe. Of course if the code without reflection is of similar complexity as the code with reflection then I'd avoid it. But the disadvantages of reflection, done right are pretty small.

Comment: Interesting - your "mini view models" are what I called [PropertyModels](http://code.google.com/p/pdx/wiki/PropertyModel) in my PDX library. I wouldn't necessarily recommend it for production code, but you might find the ideas interesting. You can set up strategies/conventions to customize the Property Model to a project's needs (I think)

Comment: Why use the miniView Models? can't you do this just with bindings and clasic MVVM. could you explain the reason for this, maybe the solution involves changing this.

Comment: @default karamer. Will take a look at your lib - PropertyModel is most definitely a name upgrade from miniViewModel!

Comment: @Ariel. In this situation, I want to eliminate unnecessary duplicate code and facilitate data binding. To my mind, this *is* classic MVVM

Comment: @SeanThoman - not sure how to make use of that CreateDelegate in my code. How about you demonstrate as an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing a binder class to manage the binding. In this case I have used `PropertyBinding`.

```
public class PropertyBinding
{
    public static PropertyBinding To(ViewModel vm, Name name, string label)
    {
        return new PropertyBinding { ViewModel = vm, Getter = new Func<string>(delegate() { return name.Value; }), Setter = new Action<string>(delegate(string value) { name.Value = value; }), Label = label };
    }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public Func<string> Getter { get; set; }

    public Action<string> Setter { get; set; }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.Get(); }
        set { this.Set(value); }
    }

    internal string Get()
    {
        // Implement UpdatePersonNamePropert here.

        // Maybe convert culture before returning.
        return this.Getter();
    }

    internal void Set(string value)
    {
        // Maybe convert culture before storing.
        this.Setter(value);
    }
}
```

It would be called like:

```
LastName = new PersonNamePropertyTextBox(PropertyBinding.To(Model, Model.GetPersonName().LastName, PeopleResources.LastName_Label));
```

Please note that `Model.GetPersonName().LastName` must return a pointer type not a value type otherwise the LastName can not be updated when the Setter is called. For example:

```
public sealed class Name
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In this example PersonName is implemented as below however your implmentation may be different.

```
public class PersonName
{
    public Name LastName { get; set; }

    public Name FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Without all your class information and the strong types associated with some of the variables you used it was hard to validate but I think this should get you out of trouble.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bernie, this is exactly what I asked for in principal but I am not grokking it. For example, the Model.GetPersonName().LastName won't compile as an arg to the requested Name parameter. Is Name supposed to be a wrapper that is new'd up somewhere not shown? Is PropertyBinding just a class you made up, or does it relate to something in the framework (dynamic?). What am I missing?

Comment: Ah yes I see the problem. Are you able to post GetPersonName() and the PersonName type. Ideally you would implement a Get/Set function on PersonName through an interface which is how I have done it in the past. PropertyBinding is just a custom class.

Comment: See my update for how I implemented the PersonName model not knowing it's full implementation.